# Angular filter поиск по нескольким словам

Tags: javascript, angularjs, поиск

Когда Ввожу одно слово ищет прекрасно, но если нужно найти к примеру по двум значениям например Имя и Страна то фильтр не ищет. Понимаю что нужно писать кастомный фильтр. все перерыл не могу понять в какую сторону смотреть

```
<div class="gradientborder">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="$search" ng-model="searchPlayers"  >
</div>
<div class="items"  ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <div ng-repeat="todo in players | filter:searchPlayers" class="item">
        <div class="player-name"> 
            {{todo.name}}
        </div> 
        <div class="player-info">
           id: {{todo.id}}, position: {{todo.position}}, jerseyNumber: {{todo.jerseyNumber}},
           dateOfBirth: {{todo.dateOfBirth}}, nationality: {{todo.nationality}}, contractUntil: {{todo.contractUntil}}
           , <br> marketValue: {{todo.marketValue}}
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

js file ниже

```
var SearchApp = angular.module('SearchApp',[]);
SearchApp.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('players.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.players = res.data;   
        });
});
```

Пример данных

```
{  
      "id":242,
      "name":"Abdul Rahman Baba",
      "position":"Left-Back",
      "jerseyNumber":6,
      "dateOfBirth":"1994-07-02",
      "nationality":"Ghana",
      "contractUntil":"2020-06-30",
      "marketValue":"10,000,000 �"
   },
   {  
      "id":435,
      "name":"Falcao",
      "position":"Centre Forward",
      "jerseyNumber":9,
      "dateOfBirth":"1986-02-10",
      "nationality":"Colombia",
      "contractUntil":"2016-06-30",
      "marketValue":"35,000,000 �"
   },
```

Надо найти: Abdul Rahman Baba Left-back.
искать нужно все через один инпут
Поиск должен найти вот этого игрока. 
Либо так:
Надо найти: Left-back England
Поиск должен найти всех игроков Англии на позиции  Left-back

Comment: http://vicatto.com/json/ - тестовый сервер

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11PIt-jigww

Comment: не дает ответ на то как найти к примеру John London

Comment: вы там видосы все посмотрите - очень грамотно объясняется там

Comment: смотрел, все равно не понятно, как ввести в инпут два значения и получить нужный результат, нашел решение только на разных инпутах не подходит

Comment: Добавь в сам вопрос: пример данных, которые фильтруются, пример ввода и пример того, что по этому вводу ожидается увидеть

Comment: добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: именно в таком виде - нельзя, так как неизвестно в каком месте заканчивается имя и начинается другое поле

Comment: То есть через один инпут я не смогу найти Игроков Англии играющих в полузащите. Введя в инпут England Left-back ?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко, сможете, если сможете определить что нужно искать отдельно `England`, отдельно `Left-Back` - если не сможете разделить так, то нахождение может оказаться проблематичным

Comment: @Grundy Есть ли пример для того как Вы предложили?

Comment: Так, это тестовое задание и его надо самостоятельно сделать!!! Ваше умение пользоваться Stackoverflow мы оценим отдельно :)

Comment: Хотелось бы от Вас тогда после проверки, услышать решение данного вопроса :)

Answer (score 2):

Суть в том, что вам нужно реализовать 2 фильтра технически, а не один. Т.к. идет отбор по двум значениям: по имени и по стране.

**Как реализовать фильтрацию коллекции по более, чем одному свойству**

Переменная для фильтра (`searchPlayers`) должна быть объектом со свойствами, совпадающими по имени с полями, по которым должна осуществляться фильтрация.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchPlayers.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchPlayers.city">

<div ng-repeat="player in players | filter:searchPlayers">
  <p>
    Имя:    {{player.name}}
    Страна: {{player.city}}
  </p>
</div>
```

***UPDATE***

**"Костыльный вариант" для использования одного поля ввода**

У каждого элемента коллекции добавить свойство, в котором будут присутствовать все значения, по которым должен производиться поиск.

Например:

```
players.push({
    name:         'Вася',
    surname:      'Пупкин',
    sity:         'Москва',
    searchString: 'Вася Пупкин Москва'
});
```

Затем, производить фильтрацию именно по свойству `searchString`

Я НЕ сторонник этого варианта, т.к. происходит дублирование информации, что априори неверный подход к решению задач.

**Лучшими вариантами будут:**

- создание под каждый фильтр свой инпут
- написать функцию, которая будет парсить строку, введенную в один инпут, и по каким-то определенным условиям присваивать значения разнообразным нужным св-вам объекта для фильтрации.

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="searchPlayers.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchPlayers.city"> - но так получается ведь два инпута? а мне нужно через один, или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко Я вам написал, как делать фильтрацию более чем по одному свойству - достаточную основу для решения вашей задачи.

Присвоение данных может происходить и в js-code ($scope.searchPlayers.name). 

В вашем случае потребуется функция, которая парсит введенные данные в инпут, и каким-то образом присваивает какие-то значения определенным св-вам $scope.searchPlayers. 

1) Наиболее простой вариант, это иметь инпуты под каждый фильтр 2) Наиболее сложный (с 1 инпутом) - разработка парсера строки
3) Не самый правильный, но решающий проблему (с 1 инпутом) - смотрите обновленный ответ.

Comment: спасибо, буду думать

Answer (score 0):

Задача фильтрации ,при использовании всего одного поля ввода, становится весьма не тривиальной. Так как неизвестно как разбивать введенную строку, чтобы искать по конкретным полям.

Например:

Введено - *Abdul Rahman Ghana*
Как определить, что `Ghana` - это не часть имени, а национальность?

В простейшем случае можно разбить по пробелам и искать полученные подстроки, но это не дает никаких указаний по каким из полей нужно проверять.

Например:

```js
var SearchApp = angular.module('SearchApp', []);
SearchApp.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.players = [{
    "id": 242,
    "name": "Abdul Rahman Baba",
    "position": "Left-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 6,
    "dateOfBirth": "1994-07-02",
    "nationality": "Ghana",
    "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
    "marketValue": "10,000,000"
  }, {
    "id": 435,
    "name": "Falcao",
    "position": "Centre Forward",
    "jerseyNumber": 9,
    "dateOfBirth": "1986-02-10",
    "nationality": "Colombia",
    "contractUntil": "2016-06-30",
    "marketValue": "35,000,000"
  }, {
    "id": 435,
    "name": "Falcao",
    "position": "Left",
    "jerseyNumber": 9,
    "dateOfBirth": "1986-02-10",
    "nationality": "Colombia",
    "contractUntil": "2016-06-30",
    "marketValue": "35,000,000"
  }, {
    "id": 435,
    "name": "Falcao",
    "position": "Left",
    "jerseyNumber": 9,
    "dateOfBirth": "1986-02-10",
    "nationality": "Colombia",
    "contractUntil": "2016-06-30",
    "marketValue": "35,000,000"
  }];
  $scope.search = function(o, i, a) {
    if (!$scope.searchPlayers) return true;
    var filter = $scope.searchPlayers.split(' ');
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    return filter.every(function(f) {
      return keys.some(function(key) {
        return !key.startsWith('$$') && (this[key] + '').indexOf(f) > -1;
      }, o);
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="SearchApp" ng-controller="ctrl2">
  <div class="gradientborder">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="$search" ng-model="searchPlayers">
  </div>
  <div class="items" ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <div ng-repeat="todo in players | filter:search" class="item">
      <div class="player-name">
        {{todo.name}}
      </div>
      <div class="player-info">
        id: {{todo.id}}, position: {{todo.position}}, jerseyNumber: {{todo.jerseyNumber}}, dateOfBirth: {{todo.dateOfBirth}}, nationality: {{todo.nationality}}, contractUntil: {{todo.contractUntil}} ,
        <br>marketValue: {{todo.marketValue}}
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```